# Ajax doesn't update properly each time

Tags: ajax

I wrote different code (at least twice) where Ajax is supposed to change an innerHTML-value by a database call (GET). While the first requests succedes in a 100 % of the time (changing a value in the database) the next commands that extracts the new Information to update the HTML-file fails in about 20-30 % of the time, receiving the wrong response from the xerver (an old value).

I tried tracking the error but can't find it since it only appears sometimes after a call. The following code is just the relevant part of my problem.

```
<p>I like <b><span id="numCom"><?php echo liked_comments(); ?></span></b> comments.</p>

// Each comment has a likeComment and CountComments function that triggers the Ajax: 
let likeIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("like-icon");
    for(let i = 0; i < likeIcon.length; i++){
        likeIcon[i].addEventListener("click", likeComment);
        likeIcon[i].addEventListener("click", countComments);
    }


function likeComment(){
        let child = this.children[0];
        let mainID = this.parentElement.parentElement.id;
        url = "ajax/like_comment.php";
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.onload = function(){
            if(this.status == 200){
                let result = this.responseText;
                if(result == "t"){
                    child.classList.remove("red-text");
                } else if (result == "f") {
                    child.classList.add("red-text");
                }
            }
       }
       xhr.send("com_id=" + mainID);
    }

    function countComments(){
        let numCom = document.getElementById("numCom");
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let url = "ajax/count_liked_comments.php";
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        xhr.onload = function(){
            if(this.status == 200){
                numCom.innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhr.onerror = function(){
            console.log("Error");
        };
        xhr.send();
    }

// In the php-files these functions are executed:


function like_comment($id){
    global $db;
    $check_query = "SELECT liked FROM comments WHERE comment_id = $id LIMIT 1";
    $check_result = mysqli_query($db, $check_query);
    while($stm = mysqli_fetch_array($check_result)){
        $l = $stm['liked'];
    }
    if($l == 0){
        // UPDATE TO 1
        $query = "UPDATE comments SET liked = 1 WHERE comment_id = $id LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        return $result;
    } else if($l == 1) {
        // UPDATE TO 0
        $query = "UPDATE comments SET liked = 0 WHERE comment_id = $id LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        return $result;
    } 
}

function is_liked($id){
    global $db;
    $check_query = "SELECT liked FROM comments WHERE comment_id = $id LIMIT 1";
    $check_result = mysqli_query($db, $check_query);
    while($stm = mysqli_fetch_array($check_result)){
        $l = $stm['liked'];
    }
    return $l;
}

function liked_comments(){
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT comment_id FROM comments WHERE liked = 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    return mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
```

The code ist just a demonstration and not really neccessary to understand the problem. In another project. I change the value of a table row via Ajax and afterwards want to update the result. This only happens in about 70 to 80% of the time. All the other times and old value is returned

Comment: What is the purpose of `$l = $stm['liked'];` in your while-loops? To find the last?

Comment: It returns if the button made a like or dislike action (it toggles)